# Bind filter in angular-ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm trying to filter ui grid based on a value from the bar chart, but I don't know how to bind this value in ui grid.

In table directive, there is isolated scope with `country` to be passed:

```
app.directive("countryItem", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "table.html",
    //isolated scope and 2-way bind country
    scope: {
      country: "="
    }
  };
});
```

The next would be binding in ui grid.. I've tried with directly binding in grid definition (`filter:country`), but it doesn't work:

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-resize-columns class="grid" external-scopes="$scope" filter:country></div>
```

Please take a look at the [plunker with ui grid](http://plnkr.co/edit/RyWoQ1AVOGgire2svn1y?p=preview), and here is the [working plunker with custom table](http://plnkr.co/edit/7uW10HDLWa6wc27xKEf2?p=preview) (what I'm trying to do with ui grid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/5LBpfCRgdaIIqQKJKhgs?p=preview.

You need to set the `filter.term` dynamically when the country changes.

```
  $scope.$watch('country', function () {
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0].filter.term = $scope.country;
    $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN )
  });
```